# How to utilize Azure Content Search without Indexing Storage?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

We have an app that uses SqlServer for document basics/metadata and the documents themselves are kept in blob storage.  We don't want to use an Indexer  - prefer instead to insert/update the search documents when we desire via the search api, however, we DO want Content search.  Is there a way to provide into the search api a url to the document and have Azure index the document in the background?  Or some other way to to handle it?

Comment: I'm afraid that without an Indexer there's no other way (besides coding the extraction / pushing to Azure Cognitive Search by yourself)

Comment: DeannaD - Why do you not want to use an indexer?

Comment: My understanding is that to index the content you have to point the indexer at storage, but my metadata is not there it's in a SQL db and I need to search on both metadata and content.

Comment: Hi DeannaD, you should be able to accomplish data from the metadata and content from two datasources in the same search index by using two indexers instead of just one, with the assumption that you are able to correlate the id value between the two datasources.  Here is a tutorial we have that demonstrates this, it uses Cosmos DB and blob but you should be able to easily replace Cosmos DB with SQL for your use case. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/tutorial-multiple-data-sources

Comment: Thanks @CareyHalton I will look into that!

Comment: Another possible solution is to populate the metadata on your blob with data from your database.  You could then just write code to keep the metadata in sync with the db rather than creating the docs in the index.